# Create array of "positions"

Tags: list-manipulation

How do I create an array `a` of generic depth $n+1$, such that exactly:

```
a[[i1]][[i2]]...[in]] = {i1,i2,...,in} ?
```

In words, such that the last-level arrays are arrays telling exactly their position in the previous levels?

Thanks.

Comment: @Kuba wow, much more elegant than my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
Table[{i, j, k, l}, {i, 4}, {j, 2}, {k, 4}, {l, 3}]
```

If `dimList` is a list of the desired dimenions then you can automate this via

```
makeArray[dimList_List] := Table[
  Array[x, Length[dimList]],
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ Transpose@{Array[x, Length[dimList]], dimList}]
]
```

-------**Edit**-------------

Kuba's solution in the comments is much more elegant:

```
Array[List,dimList]
```

Comment: Yes...but the depth is unknown and unfixed. How do I make it work for every depth?

Comment: Yup! Thank you.

Comment: I edited to make the structure a little more transparent